# Reverse numbering for subsections

Tags: numbering, subsection

Why doesn’t this (https://texblog.org/2013/04/03/reverse-numbering-for-chapters-sections-etc/) work for subsections?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\regtotcounter{subsection}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\number\numexpr\c@subsection@totc-\c@subsection+1\relax}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Subsection}
    \Blindtext
\section{Second Section}
    \Blindtext
\section{Third Section}
    \Blindtext
\section{Fourth Section}
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

I hoped for 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: It looks like the subsection counter is resetting to 0 when you have a new section (remove the last 3 sections, and this works fine).  Are you wanting to have multiple sections where the subsections count backwards, or just this one?

Comment: I want all sections to be counted backwards to 1. (Background: It's useful for living documents, where reference to entries remains stable even if a new entry is added to the top of the document)

Answer (score 5):

You need to save the total number of subsections when a new section starts off (and at end document). Thus you can do the subtraction (after a couple of LaTeX runs).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\save@subsection}
\AtEndDocument{\save@subsection}
\newcommand{\save@subsection}{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\savesubsectionnumber{\arabic{section}}{\arabic{subsection}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\savesubsectionnumber}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{savedsubsection#1}{#2}%
}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{%
  \the\numexpr
    \ifcsname savedsubsection\arabic{section}\endcsname
      \csname savedsubsection\arabic{section}\endcsname+1-
    \fi
    \value{subsection}%
  \relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\subsection{Fourth Subsection}

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsection{Third Subsection}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that `\section` saves in the aux file the current value of `section` and of `subsection` in a form that allows to define macros indexed by the section number expanding to the number of subsections.

[image]

Comment: My output is different though I copied your code and compiled several times. TOC says: 1. First section, then 1, 2, 3, 4 for the subsections (instead of 4, 3, 2, 1), then 2 Second section, 3, 2, 1 (as intended)

Comment: @Alex You probably have added something else…

Comment: No, I checked again: Copied it to a blank file, compiled several times. Wrong numbering for the first section

Comment: @Alex Sorry, but I retried the file and it yields the expected output.

Comment: Any idea what might be the reason? Can other users reproduce one or the other version???

Comment: @Alex Do you get any error message? The only possibility I see is that you have an outdated version of LaTeX.